# ¿Como puedo hacer para ejecutar un metodo cada 24 horas en cierto horario En JAVA?

Tags: java

Estoy buscando una manera para ejecutar un método automáticamente, que hace un vuelco en la base de datos, cada 24 hs en cierta hora

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que pregunta confusa.. vos queres un cron... ahora.. depende del sistema operativo como hacerlo.. es mas.. java no se que tiene que ver con tu problema, salvo que tengas un programa en java abierto las 24 horas...

Comment: Usando un cron. Usando un scheduler (quartz, por ejemplo).

Comment: te recomiendo leer el articulo [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.